# Dynamic disabled input

Tags: reactjs

I want to make an input field disabled on the basis of prop variable.

I am doing like this:

```
<input {isDisabled ? 'disabled' : ''}>
```

But this is not working. Then how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input disabled={isDisabled ? true : false}>
```

You have to use like this It's working.

Comment: When I check inspect I get <input disabled= '' />. But when I console.log(isDisable) I get the value as true or false

Comment: I tried this also <input disabled= "false" /> then also it is showing <input disabled= '' /> in inspect

Comment: because it gets Boolean value, not a String. if you pass as a string then it will get Default false value.

Comment: Then why this is also not working `<input disabled= "false" />`. I used that then also the field is disabled

Comment: you have to pass the value as a boolean, not string.

Comment: here is link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: <input disabled= false /> I have done like this, then I am getting this: `Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text`

Comment: <input disabled={false} / > you have pass like this.

Comment: one last thing how to pass the value of prop. Could you please give the example

Comment: Can you please help me in this

Comment: <componet isDisabled= 'false'  /> I used this but this is not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `disabled` prop:

```
<input disabled={isDisabled}/>

// Same but less readable
<input disabled={isDisabled ? true : false}/>
<input {...{disabled: isDisabled}}/>
```

For example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isDisabled, toggle] = useReducer(p => !p, false);
  return (
    <>
      <input disabled={isDisabled} />
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit stupefied-borg-5zc1r]

Comment: You don't use any prop, your code won't even compile because it is not a valid JSX syntax. The nearest valid syntax is destructive operator (`...`) like in my first example.

Comment: When I check inspect I get <input disabled= '' />.  But when I console.log(isDisable) I get the value as true or false

Comment: I tried this also `<input disabled= "false" />` then also it is showing `<input disabled= '' />` in inspect

Comment: Its not HTML, its JSX, such code is not valid, please read the tutorials of React: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: Could not get it. Whatever value I pass to it. It is alwalys disabled.

Comment: You have a codesandbox example, what is the problem

Comment: one last thing how to pass the value of prop. Could you please give the example

Comment: Please ask another question instead, if its not related to current topic.

Comment: `<componet isDisabled= 'false'  />` I used this but this is not working

Comment: Could you please help me in this?

Comment: Please, just ask another question its not related. And you better read the docs its well explained there.